# How to disable popup in webView?

Tags: ios, swift

I presented a webView for payment in an iOS phone, then after the transaction, it will pop an alertmessage saying success in both web and phone. I want to disable that alertmessage in the phone. Is there a function in webView that I can use?

```
func proceedToWeb(urlAppend:String) {

    let vc = WebContentViewController()
    if var urlStr = incident?.url {
        urlStr.append("?uid=\(UserManager.shared.uid)&q=\(urlAppend)")
        print("urlStr \(urlStr)")
        vc.webURL = URL(string:urlStr)
        vc.formViewController = self
    }

    let nav = NavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    nav.willRotate = false
    nav.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = false
    self.present(nav, animated: true) {

    }


}
```

Comment: is it alert of web page and it's shown on web browser too?

Comment: Yes. when I remove the alert in the web, it also removed in the app

Comment: Did you managed to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can send post message to your web using `javascript` and disable it from web.

```
// create javascript code as string
let javascriptSource = "window.post.accept({shouldShowAlert: false})"

// evaluate it on webView
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptSource)
```

More details you can find [here](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/javascript-manipulation-on-ios-using-webkit-2b1115e7e405)

Comment: It's crashing when I add the code. It says:
                                      
    validateFunctionArguments:3516: failed assertion `Fragment 
     Function(ca_uber_fragment_lp0_cp0_fo0): The pixel format 
    (MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Unorm) of the texture (name:<null>) bound at index 0 is 
    incompatible with the data type (MTLDataTypeHalf) of the texture parameter 
    (img_tex_0A [[texture(0)]]). MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Unorm is compatible with the 
    data type(s) (
    float
    ).'

Comment: I removed the code but it still keeps on crashing.... it was working before I added the code above...

Comment: @StephensonAng Seems unreal :)

Comment: Moreover, this code won't solve your problem, but shows you how you can send `javascript` to your website. Then, you should handle this call with `shouldShowAlert` on your web.